# Local Storage is messing up my variable increments

Tags: javascript, local-storage

When I set variables to localStorage, like so..

```
localStorage.setItem('gold', gold);
```

And then I recall them like this...

```
gold = localStorage.getItem('gold');
```

It messes up some of my functions that worked before, for instance

```
setInterval(function(){
  ore += orepm;
}, 60000);
```

Instead of making it 112 from 100 (+12 each minute), it makes it 10012. It's basically adding the number to the end of the starting number, like a string. I believe that it has to do with localhost changing format but I'm not sure and have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Hint #1: `typeof`

Comment: How does `gold` relate to `ore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is your friend. Although it's unclear from your question how `gold` relates to `ore` (or indeed `orepm`), you should use `parseInt()` (or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) if needed) when retrieving the value:

```
gold = parseInt( localStorage.getItem('gold') );
```

It's worth noting some of the intracicies of `parseInt()` -- for example:

```
parseInt('1kjjdfud') == 1;
```

So you may wish to use Javascript's casting mechanism (i.e. [`Number('1')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)), if you correctly handle `NaN`:

```
gold = Number( localStorage.getItem('gold') );
```

Comment: Thanks I just used gold as an example for how I set the localStorage item, I have a ton of items to collect so this is very helpful. And if i could add, you would not have to parse it for setting the items Right?

Comment: @I.Smith it may be worthwhile to just consider saving an entire JSON object with `JSON.stringify()`, and retrieving it with `JSON.parse()` instead of storing/ retrieving single key and string values.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
gold = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('gold'), 10);
```

... to convert the returned String to a Number.

**EDIT**

Added radix; good to have it included at all times.

Comment: Don't forget the second argument to `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks; forgot that one ... added it.

Comment: @Barmar there is really no reason to add it.

Comment: I realize that `parseInt` will default to a base-10, but I have always found it best to include it as a general rule of thumb.  It's simply one of those things that I categorize under good coding practices.  Clarity over functionality is often a good rule of thumb ...

Comment: It is unnecessary redundancy. "good coding practices" --- there is no objectives behind it, not sure how adding a parameter that does not change anything makes code better `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Adding the parameter makes the "objective" clear (and that's the objective here ... the end goal) when someone is reading the code.  It may not be me and it may be a less experienced programmer.  I'll argue this all night, but it is the way I code; good practices and future proofed.  You can disagree if you like, but it is how I code.